# Entity reference auto complete field is missing value on ajax callback

Tags: entities, ajax, 9

I have an entity reference field on my content type using the autocomplete widget.

I'm adding an ajax callback to that field using this in a form alter:

```
$form['field_er']['widget'][0]['target_id']['#ajax'] = [
  'callback' => '::ajaxCallback',
  'event' => 'autocompleteselect',
  'wrapper' => 'nm-resend-selector',
  'progress' => [
    'type' => 'throbber',
    'message' => t('Updating.'),
  ],
];
```

The ajax call triggers when I select an entity, but in my form alter when I use `$formState->getValue('field_er')` the target_id is null, when it should be the id of the entity I selected.

How do I get at the selected entity?

Edit: I looked into FormState::input to see if I could get the value from there, but the value there is 'a' which is the text I entered to trigger the autocomplete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I was just using the wrong event, switching the event to 'autocompleteclose' gets me the value I need.